# Can't Extract value from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, docusignapi

I have problems with my code. I have created a class to search for job id or task id. But I can't retrieve the envelope_id in my MySQL. the value should be TESTTEST

```
<?php
class Envelope {
    private $_db, $_data;
    public function __construct($taskidorjobid = null, $taskid = null) {
        $this -> _db = DB::getInstance();
        //$this -> _sessionName = Config::get('session/session_name');
        //$this -> _cookieName = Config::get('remember/cookie_name');
        if ($taskidorjobid == null && $taskid == null) {

        } elseif ($taskid == null) {
            $this -> findtaskid($taskidorjobid);
        } else {
            $this -> find($taskidorjobid, $taskid);
        }
    }

    public function findtaskid($taskid = null) {
        if ($taskid) {
            $field = 'id';
            $data = $this -> _db -> get('task', array($field, '=', $taskid));
            if ($data -> count()) {
                $this -> _data = $data -> first();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function find($jobid = null, $taskid = null) {
        if ($jobid and $taskid) {
            //$field = 'id';
            //$data = $this -> _db -> get('task', array($field, '=', $task));
            $data = $this -> _db -> query("select * from document where job = " . $jobid . " and taskid = " . $taskid);
            if ($data -> count()) {
                $this -> _data = $data -> first();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function findenvelopeid($taskid = null, $version = null) {

            $sql = "select envelope_id from document where taskid = ?, version = ?, latestflag = ?";
            $param = array($taskid, $version, "yes");


            $data = $this-> _db->query($sql, $param);



       //foreach ($data->results() as $row) {
        if ($data -> count()) {
                $this -> _data = $data -> first();
                $envelope_id = $this -> _data -> envelope_id;
                return $envelope_id;

        }
        return false;

       }
}        
?>
```

Then in my another set of php file, I called the function findenvelopeid, but it doesn't return any value. I can echo my $tid as the $taskid.

```
$envelope = new Envelope();
$envelopeid = $envelope->findenvelopeid($tid,"signed_online");
echo "Envelope ID: ".$envelopeid. "<br>";
```

my query function developed by my coder is:

```
public function query($sql,$params=array(), $options=array()){
    $this->_error=false;
    if($this->_query=$this->_pdo->prepare($sql)){
        $x=1;
        if(count($params)){
            foreach($params as $param){
                //if(count($options)>=$x){
                    //var_dump("DB sql: " . $sql . "<br/> x: " . $x . ", param: " . $param . ", options:" . $options[$x-1]);
                //   $this->_query->bindValue($x,$param, $options[$x-1]);
                //}else{
                    //var_dump("DB sql: " . $sql . "<br/> x: " . $x . ", param: " . $param);
                   $this->_query->bindValue($x,$param);
                //}
                $x++;
            }
        }
        if($this->_query->execute()){
            $this->_results=$this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count=$this->_query->rowCount();
        }else{
            //var_dump("<br /> errorcode " . $this->_pdo->errorCode() . "<br />error info:");
            //print_r($this->_pdo->errorInfo());
            $this->_error=true;
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Thats a bit if a mess. Why `$db = DB::getInstance();` when your constructor already did that and saved it on `$this->_db` which you already knew as you then use `$this->_db` in the method code

Comment: Also if you are using `marked parameters` i.e. `?` you need to prepare the sql statement and then `->execute()`  it

Comment: Check the [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: That's really weird. Cos my previous coder who did the codes, he didnt use prepare and execute.

Comment: like this: 
`public static function getalldocumentsbytaskid($taskid){
        $db = DB::getInstance();
        $documents = array();
        $sql = "select * from document where taskid=? and latestflag=?";
        $param = array($taskid, "yes");
        $data = $db->query($sql, $param);
        //$data = $db->get("document",array("taskid", "=", $taskid));
        if($data){
            foreach($data->results() as $row){
                $documents[]=new Document($row->id);
            }
        }
        return $documents;
    }`

Comment: Maybe none of the code he wrote used `marker parameters` The query in the `findenvelopeid` method is using `?` for data placeholders

Comment: I have added a snippet of the query. It seems to do with the marker parameters!

Comment: Oh great, a class wrapper for the PDO Class.

Comment: nvm, I have fixed the code, my sql `where` shouldn't put commas

Comment: Oh woops, totally missed that. Haa

Answer (score 0):

Blimey, I should use `AND` instead of a `,` in my where clause.